# Undeclared identifier when trying to pass in object

Tags: c++

I am trying to pass in an object of type "Restaurant", but it is giving me this error – "Undeclared Identifier", but I made sure to include namespace, spell it right and I cannot seem to find the source of this issue, though it is probably obvious.

Can anybody take a look and tell me whats going on?

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "menu.h"
#include "pizza.h"

using namespace std;

struct employee {
    int id;
    string password;
    string first_name;
    string last_name;
};

struct hours {
    string day;
    string open_hour;
    string close_hour;
};

#include "restaurant.h"

string get_login_input();
int get_id();
string get_password();
void employee_options(Restaurant &);
//void customer_options();
void print_employee();
int get_employee_option();
void selection(int);

#endif
```

The problem line is `void employee_options(Restaurant &).`

I pass it in main like:

```
int main()
{
    Restaurant r;
    employee_options(r);
// ...
```

and the defined function looks like

```
void employee_options(Restaurant &r) {
~~~
}
```

The error code Im getting is:

```
In file included from restaurant.h:3:0,
                 from restaurant.cpp:1:
Header.h:28:23: error: variable or field ‘employee_options’ declared void
 void employee_options(Restaurant &);
                       ^
Header.h:28:23: error: ‘Restaurant’ was not declared in this scope
Header.h:28:35: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 void employee_options(Restaurant &);
```

Let me know if more information is needed. Thank you in advance to any help

edit: Restaurant.h looks like this:

```
#ifndef RESTAURANT_H
#define RESTAURANT_H
#include "Header.h"
#include "menu.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Restaurant {
private:
    // Members
    menu Menu;
    employee* employees;
    hours* week;
    string name;
    string phone;
    string address;
    int num_employees;
public:
    // Constructor
    Restaurant();
    // copy constructor
    Restaurant(const Restaurant& old_object);
    // Assignment operator overload
    const Restaurant& operator=(const Restaurant& old_object);

    // Accessor functions
    void set_name(string);
    void set_phone(string);
    void set_address(string);

    // Mutator functions
    string get_name() const;
    string get_phone() const;
    string get_address() const;
    void get_employees();

    //need to include constructors, copy constructors, assignment operator overload

    void load_data(); //reads from files to correctly populate menu, employees, hours, etc.
    void fill_r_info();
    void fill_hours(ifstream &file);
    bool login(int id, string password);
    void view_menu();
    void view_hours();
    void view_address();
    void view_phone();
    void search_menu_by_price();
    void search_by_ingredients();
    void place_order(pizza* selection);
    void change_hours();
    void add_to_menu();
    void remove_from_menu();
    void view_orders();
    void remove_orders();

    // Destructor
    ~Restaurant();
};

#endif
```

Comment: Just a tip, never ever put include directives below a `using namespace` statement. Not to mention `using namespace std;` is bad practice in and of itself (especially inside a header file).

Comment: What does `restaurant.h` look like?

Comment: I added in restaurant

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Restaurant` has not been declared yet when it is used in `employee_options`. This is because you have a recursive dependency between `restaurant.h` and `Header.h`. `restaurant.h` includes `Header.h` before declaring `class Restaurant`; `Header.h` then tries to include `restaurant.h` to get Restaurant, but does nothing because of the include guards.

You could fix this by replacing `#include "restaurant.h"` in `Header.h` with a forward-declaration of Restaurant, eg: `class Restaurant;`. This will also eliminate the circular dependency, which is generally desirable.